# why is local image not showing on browser meanwhile the path is correct in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The Image am importing from my local Json data that contains the image pathname is not showing on browser and am confused why it not showing. Have use the required tag both on img src and the Json data it self

```
images: {
      mobil: "./images/portfolio/desktop/finshed-next.png",
      tablet: "./images/portfolio/tablet/finshed-next.png",
      desktop: "./images/portfolio/desktop/color.png",
    },
```

I used both codes below but they dont seem to work

```
 <img src={require(images.desktop)} alt={title} />
 <img src={images.desktop} alt={title} />
```

but if I make an import with the same path, Its working. I mean

```
import img1 from "./images/portfolio/desktop/color.png",
```

It will definitely show on the  browser.

Comment: Are the paths mentioned in the json correct? You seem to be missing `.` in the mobil and having an extra `.` in the tablet values.

Comment: @Akshay it has been edited. the path is definitely correct

Comment: Try adding {JSON.Stringify(images)} above your images and see what's coming in there

Comment: Are you aware that a local path might differ from a routing path? Are the routes `"./images/portfolio/desktop/finshed-next.png"` etc. available via your webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this should work, if you are using create-react-app.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

    const [img, setImg] = useState<string>();
    const [imgLoc, setImgLoc] = useState<string>();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (imgLoc !== undefined) {
            import(imgLoc).then(image => setImg(image));
        }
    }, [imgLoc]);

    const images = {
        mobil: "./images/portfolio/desktop/finshed-next.svg",
        tablet: "./images/portfolio/tablet/finshed-next.svg",
        desktop: "./images/portfolio/desktop/color.svg",
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h2>Image goes here</h2>
            <button onClick={() => setImgLoc(images.mobil)} />
            {img && <img src={img}/>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry and if I am wrong, I apologize in advance.

You are probably trying to avoid manually adding the image paths to components. But I can't seem to understand why you would do this.

If the images are dynamic, then in a real-world implementation, they would probably be accessible over a server (statically hosted). In this case, you would receive the src (image URLs) via an HTTP call or something similar. So you won't be importing the images.

```
... // logic to fetch the list of image URLs

... // logic to render an image tag with an src value being an image URL
```

But if the images are not changing, then you could probably just import them directly from something like an asset folder as @calimenikk mentioned.

Comment: I actually ended up importing them. Thanks for the feedback